# How can I speed up python / jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Very general question.

I am a chemist by trade, but use python for a large portion of my work for data analysis.  I recently upgraded my laptop from Intel i5 to i7 with double the RAM and yet Jupyter notebook (on Chrome) seems to process data at the same speed.  According to Windows10 task manager I'm using 30-50% of CPU and/or  GPU.  They never max out even when the code is chewing through Gb of data.

Advice on how to speed things up, or what hardware upgrades actually impact processing time?

Comment: Having more RAM means you can hold more data in memory. You need a significant change in processing/clock speed to notice a "speed up"

Comment: What comes into mind is you might need to use multithread to process them in parallel

You are seeing 30-50% CPU as your CPU might be multi-core. Your Python code does not use all the core

Comment: the i7-8650U is quad core. mostly I am processing a pandas df of 20-30 columns and 500,000 rows.  Is there a way to multi-thread a single df?